# undefined local variable or method (NameError)

Tags: ruby

This code:

```
def convert(temp)  
  new_temp = (temp - 32) * 5/9  
  return new_temp
end

fahrenheit_temp = gets.to_i
celsius_temp = convert(fahrenheit_temp)
puts celsius_temp
```

raises:

```
C:/Users/Asd/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/test/test.rb:3:in `convert': undefined local variable or method `new_temp' for main:Object (NameError)
from C:/Users/Asd/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/test/test.rb:7:in `<main>
```

Is there any help? I don't understand why the `return` method causes this problem.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. Please read "[mcve]". Use snake_case for method and variable names, notCamelCaseBecauseItIsHarderToRead. `return` is redundant as Ruby will return the last value seen. The method can be reduced to `(temp - 32) * 5/9` as a result.

Comment: question edited. thanks for the advice

Comment: If you run this concrete snippet it will work.

Comment: Did you try running the new code?  I see you still have the old error posted, referencing a variable that no longer exists.  Also, as the Tin Man suggested you can get rid of the variable assignment altogether.

Comment: yes I tried the new code and it still gives me error. sorry that I forgot to edit the error.

Answer (score 0):

It work fine for me. I use this command line:

```
ruby test.rb
```

You can try again ?

Comment: I write the code on "visual studio code". I save the .rb file and then drag and drop it on "start cmd with ruby". it gives me the same error when I try this code on aptana studio 3